# Python/Pandas Iterated Creation of DF based on unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to take a dataframe that has multiple 'ID' values and create a new dataframe for each unique 'ID' value in the original dataframe. First I attempt to make a "list" of all of the unique 'ID' values with .unique() and then in a loop add "_df" to each unique 'ID' from the list and use that to name the dataframe as well as filter for it's contents.

The data structure would look like this:

```
   ID      Date      Score  DateTime
0  1000    1/1/2022  38     2022-01-01 12:09:00
1  5000    1/1/2022  78     2022-01-01 10:07:00
2  1000    1/1/2022  92     2022-01-01 02:07:00
3  3000    1/1/2022  73     2022-01-01 02:02:00
4  3000    1/1/2022  98     2022-01-01 11:12:00
```

Pseudo Code:

```
unique_id = df['ID'].unique()

for x in unique_id:
    unique_df = x + "_df"
    
    i = 0
    while i < len(unique_df):
        unique_df = df.unique_df[i]
        i = i + 1
```

Ideal Results:

```
print(1000_df)

   ID      Date      Score  DateTime
0  1000    1/1/2022  38     2022-01-01 12:09:00
2  1000    1/1/2022  92     2022-01-01 02:07:00

print(3000_df)

3  3000    1/1/2022  73     2022-01-01 02:02:00
4  3000    1/1/2022  98     2022-01-01 11:12:00

etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Arbitrarily creating variables is a terrible idea, but you can create a dictionary that does a similar task quite easily using `groupby`:

```
>>> dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('ID')))

>>> print(dfs[1000])
     ID      Date  Score             DateTime
0  1000  1/1/2022     38  2022-01-01 12:09:00
2  1000  1/1/2022     92  2022-01-01 02:07:00

>>> print(dfs[3000])
     ID      Date  Score             DateTime
3  3000  1/1/2022     73  2022-01-01 02:02:00
4  3000  1/1/2022     98  2022-01-01 11:12:00
```